hide replies for comment section by default
I am customizing a blogger template and I am finding a difficulty on making the replies of comments hidden by default, I would like to know some hints where I am mistaking.[style-replies][html-repscript-replieslies](https://i.sstatic.net/oTuu1g7A.jpg)
trying to hide the replies by default
